# The listener for function was unable to start. Why?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm getting the following error when I run the azure function from visual studio.

> A ScriptHost error has occurred [1/19/2018 6:40:52 AM] The listener
>   for function 'MyFunctionName' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Server encountered an internal error.
>   Please try again after some time.

When I run from the command prompt by running `func host start` command. I get the following warning. and then it gets stuck on

> Host lock lease acquired by instance ID

.

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers,
>   etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(),
>   config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Azure function version: `azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.22`
I'm using Storage Accounts Blob containers and queues.

I'm connecting to **Development Storage account**, I have checked it that **storage emulator** is started.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ConnectionStrings:Default": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDb; Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "ConnectionStrings:BlobStorageAccount": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  }
}
```

**FYI.**

It was working fine before, But I have got this message in Visual Studio.

> your license has gone stale and must be updated. Check for an updated
>   license to continue using this product

So I just deleted the **%localappdata%** and **%temp%**, then I tried to run Azure function and after this, I have started getting

> The listener for function was unable to start error

So is it related to my visual studio subscription or I mistakenly deleted any required file? Or is this related to something else?

Comment: I think we're going to need some more information to be able to help you. I assume since you're having the problem you're talking about an .NET base Azure Function running on the 1.x runtime? Also, what kind of trigger are you using (storage queue, service bus queue/topic, something else)? If there's any way you can put your project somewhere out in the open (e.g. GitHub) that would be awesome, but if you can't it might just take a little more back and forth.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I updated my question

Comment: If you have your function app running in Azure (or somewhere else) using the same host ID, then that instance may take the lease, and your locally running copy would not be running functions.Make sure all of the connection you have fill down.

Comment: @JoeyCai but it’s not working with VS?

Comment: @JoeyCai any updates on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone that is encountering this issue the following may help...

Azure Durable Functions rely on TableStorage, and the latest version of Azurite (v3) currently doesn't support TableStorage. As such, pull the Azurite repo and switch to the `legacy-master` (v2) branch and then run `npm run start`.

Comment: That was a reason of my problem. Thanks!

Comment: To keep track of v3 support for TableStorage, see this issue: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/614. You may install the alpha version `npm install -g azurite@alpha` (not tested, though).

Comment: Executing durable functions was working great (uses Azurite) but "regular functions" could not start (Like it was trying to reach the Azure Storage Emulator instead of Azurite)

The solution changin `"AzureWebJobsStorage"` in `local.settings.json` to the real local connection string 
`AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=*****;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;`

That forces using Azurite in any case.

Answer (score 19):

if you are running via storage emulator locally then run func settings add **AzureWebJobsStorage** `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in `local.settings.json`

and if with a normal Azure Storage connection string using func, must set the AzureWebJobsStorage  in `local.settings.json`.
The final JSON would look like this:

```json
{
  // some variables
  "Values": {
    // some variables
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
}
```

for more [view](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/45)

Comment: The filename must be `local.settings.json`. Setting needs to be plural.

Answer (score 7):

I just witnessed this. This link https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/357 indicates **Local Storage Emulator** may not be running. I stopped debugging. Went to the Cloud Explorer and opened the local nodes to see blob content. This must have started the Local storage emulator. When I hit run again, Azure Functions Tools started up.

Comment: The timer in azure-webjobs-hosts was corrupt. It was fixed after deleting the entry.

Answer (score 6):

For me this error was showing up because I didn't have Storage Emulator installed and running. You can install Storage emulator as VS Code plugin from following link. After installing go to VS Code command palette and run `Azurite: Start Blob Service`. Then run your function locally. It will work fine.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azurite.azurite

Comment: Azurite is the way to run Storage Emulator on Mac and Linux. Alternatives to the VS Code plugin are running via a Docker container and installing the Azurite npm package: https://github.com/azure/azurite

Answer (score 6):

I solved the issue doing the following steps:
Open up a new terminal and type "azurite". The program will open and keep the window opened.
Open visual studio and try to run the function again. Voi la.

Comment: Interesting. Visual Studio was always an integrated development IDE. If "Azurite" is needed, is it an integrated environment yet?

Comment: Interesting question. After running the function for a few times there is no need to run azurite from outside visual studio. Don´t ask me why, it´s just a weird behaviour from VS.

Comment: Yeah, if you're on a mac, azurite can mimic the azure storage. Running azurite in a terminal as per this answer was the solution to my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem too and spend many time. The fix is not from me but I hope the onwer can accept it as solution it has spend me much time in past and it can help others.

The only working fix for me was written in the comment above:

> The timer in azure-webjobs-hosts was corrupt. It was fixed after
> deleting the entry. –  Marcel Gelijk  Mar 5, 2021 at 9:59

On my cases it ssems to happened if you use a timer trigger and change many on them , make duplicates or switch the time trigger to http trigger and back.  If you do som stuff for testing it could harm conflicting entries in azure-webjobs-hosts.

**So I delete all entries in locks and timers folder. On starting your timer azure functions all Entries will renewed and it worked**

Many thanks to Marcel Gelijk.

[[image: Delete all Entries in that 2 folders1]

Answer (score 3):

I am using VS-2022. This issue was resolved using following steps.

1. Run Azurite, in local machine, using below command

   azurite --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log
2. In local.settings.json, use below code:

   "Values": {

   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"}
3. (optional), start the emulator and check that there is no error

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue when I was using `ServiceBusTrigger` in my Azure functions.

[image]

In my visual studio solution I had two `Azure Functions` and I was using the same `Subscription Name` for my two Functions, where one function is to send the data to the Azure Service Bus and the other is for receiving the data.

**To Send**

```
private const string _topicName = "factfinder_topic";
private const string _subscriptionName = "subs1";
private static ITopicClient _topicClient;
private static ILogger _logger;
[FunctionName("SendDataToSubscription")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(_topicName, _subscriptionName, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log) {
    _logger = log;
    PrepareSend().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    _logger.LogInformation($ "C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

**To Receive**

```
private const string _topicName = "factfinder_topic";
private const string _subscriptionName = "subs1";
[FunctionName("FetchDataFromSubscription")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(_topicName, _subscriptionName, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log) {
    log.LogInformation($ "C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

As you could see that the value of the `_subscriptionName` is `subs1` in both case, and this is wrong, so after **changing this to my other subscription name** (`subs2`) in the `FetchDataFromSubscription` function, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

solved by following this blog.

https://markgossa.com/2018/12/azure-function-listener-for-function.html

"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start

Comment: Thanks @Muni for the pointer. Everything worked exactly as described in the blog.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue. Exiting the Visual Studio and opening it again resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: one time after  VS update it worked for me too. I think it worked, because Azurite was updated. In other cases it possible that it will not work and i had a few other cases that not worked. Only deleting entries in storage azure-webjobs-hosts then works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who bump in this kind of issue, please check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2959#issuecomment-1136356003).

After cleaning the azure storage local container, it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this error when locally running durable functions I found the easiest way to deal with it was by using the VSCode extension "Durable Functions Monitor". I find this an excellent resource for durable functions; using the extension I delete the hub in Azurite storage, which is fast. All the data from any previous executions is removed along with this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted everything inside %localappdata% and %temp% folders and started again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting something similar to this with an eraly version of Visual Studio 17.0.x, and Microsoft Azure Queue Explorer (and emulator), not Azurite.

When I upgraded to a later patch (17.6.x) then it started working. Strange that this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your azure storage account name and key to the **local.settings.json** file

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<accountName>;AccountKey=<accountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem by setting **UseDevelopmentStorage=false** in local.settings.json file.

{

"IsEncrypted": false,

  "Values": {

   "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",

    "AzureWebJobsStorage": **"UseDevelopmentStorage=false"**

 }

}