# The listener for function 'my-function' was unable to start error message in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I am getting the following error message when attempting to run my Azure Functions on my dev machine:

```
[12/28/2019 12:06:48 AM] The listener for function 'my-function' was unable to start.
[12/28/2019 12:06:48 AM] The listener for function 'my-function' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').
```

Here are the contents of my local.settings.json file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

When I delete/rename my local.settings.json file, I get a completely different error message which leads me to believe it is recognizing and reading the file.

I am using v3 of Azure Functions, and have the following set in my csproj file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

All of my NuGet packages are running the latest versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
```

I've tried the following that I've read in GitHub Issues opened for Azure Functions but none of then worked:

1. Adding AzureWebJobsStorage as an environment variable.
2. Adding an appsettings.json file with an AzureWebJobsStorage key.

Comment: Hi Mike, did you run the function success in local ? And could you please provide your function code and then I can test it for you.

Comment: Hi, Mike. Still can not start listener now?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I reverted all of my changes to the last known working state, and remade changes one by one to try to determine what caused the issue. I was able to apply all of the changes the second time around with no issues, so I'm not entirely sure what happened. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

***Update:***

Yes, if you use a locally virtualized Storage Emulator, then your Connecting String is correct.

If your firewall restricts func from accessing the Storage Account, then this error may be reported. The firewall is one of the reasons that the listener cannot access the virtual Storage Emulator.

Try disabling the firewall and see if that resolves the issue.

**Of course, it is also possible that the Storage Emulator service is not open.** Try typing

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" status
```

in cmd to check the status.

If it returns false, enter the following command to start the Storage Emulator:

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

***To sum up:***

There are usually three possible causes for this type of problem.

1.Connection string error prevents connection,

2.firewall is set

3.some services are not turned on.

In addition to these three points, there seem to be similar problems solved by copying the same code into a new project. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335887/the-listener-for-function-was-unable-to-start-why).

The reason for this problem is actually that the func listener cannot listen to Storage. The solution is to consider what causes func to fail to listen to Storage. There may be other situations, but the direction of consideration is similar.

Hope it helps.

---

***Original Answer:***

I used the same configuration as you to create the Function, but I didn't encounter the error, so I suspect the problem may be from the settings of the firewall and the virtual network.

The listener cannot access the Storage Account, try to create a dynamic container in your code, and you should encounter an access error.

Comment: I'm running it locally, with the connection string being `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`. How does the firewall or virtual network come into play? (I'm a noob with Azure Functions, so I'm sure I'm overlooking something)

Comment: @MikeCole When running a function locally, all triggers except httptrigger need to use the Storage Emulator. If the firewall restricts the listener's access to the virtual storage, then there will be problems when executing the function. Have a look of my update answer.