# The listener for function 'IngestEvents' was unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am working with implementing an azure event hub and already created the required resources in function app and Event Hub NS, Event hub and consumer group. However when I tried to run the function app locally I get the following error and it does not allow me to send messages to the Event Hub. I already configured the Listen,Send,Manage policies at the NS level. Does anyone encountered this issue?

```
The listener for function 'IngestEvents' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid. TrackingId:00000xxxxx0000xxxxx, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2022-08-01T07:29:33 (events-00)) (InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid. TrackingId:00000xxxxx0000xxxxx, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2022-08-01T07:29:33 (events-00)). Azure.Messaging.EventHubs: InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid. TrackingId:00000xxxxx0000xxxxx, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2022-08-01T07:29:33 (events-00).
```

I already tried out solutions in  [Azure Functions: There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728499/azure-functions-there-was-an-error-performing-a-read-operation-on-the-blob-stor) and [The listener for function was unable to start. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335887/the-listener-for-function-was-unable-to-start-why) but no success result.

I am using chain credentials. So mostly it authorized me through VS credentials as default.

Comment: the error message indicates that you re using azure ad rather than connectionstring in your project (which should be a good thing tho :-) )?

Comment: I imagine you need the `Azure Event Hubs Data Sender` data plane RBAC role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-event-hubs-data-sender

Comment: @Thomas I have already added Data sender/receiver roles. This is more like AD related issue as I feel.

Comment: are you using vs or vs code ? did you configure the `Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication` ?

Comment: Yes @Thomas. Verified it as well. I'm using VS. Also installed Functions core tools 4+